# How can I limit the border for a single element?

Tags: html, css

I have a list using li for my nav bar. I set a border-radius on my background so that it would be rounded. Now I just need to delete the `border-left` of the home element. Here are the snippets of code:

**HTML:**

```html
<li class="home">
    <a href="<?php echo url('/'); ?>">home</a>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```css
li.home {
    border-left:0px;
}
```

I hope this is enough context to help answer my question. Please let me know if it isn't.

Comment: What is your question? What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: @watson It doesn't remove the border for the home class.

Comment: not only removing the left border, but also removing the two round corner corresponding with the left border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try li.home { border-left:0px !important; }

Comment: @Pon-3 if this worked then you have either a [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) problem or an ordering problem. I'd address those issues directly rather than using `!important` as a fix.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want left border dont mention it..i.e dont write `border:1px solid;` or `boder-left:1px;`..only mention the borders you need like `border-right` or `border-top` and to have rounded edge use `border-top-right-radius:10px;`

EXAMPLE :: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZX8aA/)**